# Windows heap allocations call stacks - strange callstack

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory-leaks, windbg

I'm trying to analyze a managed process memory dump an suspect if for native memory leaks. In order to be able to use windbg (and use !heap extension from there) I activated user mode call stacks for the server process

I see a lot of blocks of size 68. And among those blocks (those that I could manually verify using *!heap -p -a*) there are many call-stacks of the form

```
 !heap -p -a 000000003ca5cfd0
    address 000000003ca5cfd0 found in
    _HEAP @ 1ea0000
              HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
        000000003ca5cfa0 0009 0000  [00]   000000003ca5cfd0    00068 - (busy)
        7766bbed ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x000000000001913b
        7fef7b76a57 msvcr120!malloc+0x000000000000005b
        7fef7b76967 msvcr120!operator new+0x000000000000001f
        7fe9a5cdaf8 +0x000007fe9a5cdaf8
```

Do you have any idea what are these allocations because they take hundreds of MB on my dump file ?

**EDIT**
lm shows the following around the area **7fe9a5cdaf8**  (truncated)

```
start             end                module name
00000000`773b0000 00000000`774cf000   kernel32   (pdb symbols)
00000000`774d0000 00000000`775ca000   user32     (deferred)
00000000`775d0000 00000000`77779000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)
00000000`77790000 00000000`77797000   psapi      (deferred)
00000000`777a0000 00000000`777a3000   normaliz   (deferred)
00000001`3f810000 00000001`3f818000   ManagedService  (deferred)             
000007fe`dd2d0000 000007fe`de398000   System_Web_ni   (deferred)
```

Comment: You're missing symbols for whatever module is around `7fe9a5cdaf8`.  Run `lm` and look for the module that the address corresponds to, and see if you can't find symbols for it.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk In the area between ManagedService and System_Web_ni there is no module mapped..

Comment: Could be dynamic code in that case.  I'm not sure what a next step would be other than to add a [breakpoint when 68 bytes are allocated](http://codediary.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/4/) to try and get a better stack trace.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk That could be a valid point but have it on a user dump. I wonder how can we recognize memory allocated for user mode call stacks for the process. The stacks should be part of the process dump I supose

Comment: Yuck, that's rough. You've got my upvote!

Comment: Just as a side note: the command to get a symbol from an address is `ln <addr>` (`list nearest`), but wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that there was no native image created for your application (using NGen). In that case the module (DLL) only contains IL code which will never be executed. So, from native point of view, there won't be any stacks pointing to inside the module.

Instead the IL code will be JIT compiled to another location in memory, e.g. 7fe9a5cdaf8 in your case. That's where real code is executed, so that's what you see from native side.

To revert a JIT compiled instruction into its .NET method descriptor, do the following:

```
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .loadby sos mscorwks ; *** .NET 2
0:000> .loadby sos clr ; *** .NET 4

0:000> !ip2md 7fe9a5cdaf8
```

The output should then show the .NET method name (example here, since I don't have your dump):

```
MethodDesc: 000007ff00033450
Method Name: ManagedService.Program.Main()
Class: 000007ff00162438
MethodTable: 000007ff00033460
mdToken: 0600001f
Module: 000007ff00032e30
IsJitted: yes
CodeAddr: 000007ff00170120
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion. In the end it was needed to set a breakpoint on a live process for 68 bytes allocations and curiously  it was needed to "decode" multiple callstack frames using !ip2md instructions. The code was c++ CLI, allocating some native memory that was leaking. I wonder if I can find out more about this ip2md in other places...